# PHP code not inserting data into MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Basically i've been scratching my head at this and I still can't figure out why it's not inserting.

I'm 100% sure the database is connected as it's fetching information just fine, however the following code fails to insert anything into the database. I've checked for spelling mistakes, i've checked from deprecated php code etc, and have used mysqli and mysql.

```
<?php 

include_once "settings.php";


if (isset($_POST['sendMessage']) && isset($_POST['messageTo']) && isset($_POST['messageBody'])){

    $messageTo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['messageTo']);
    $messageBody = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['messageBody']);

    $query= "INSERT INTO inbox (`msgTo`, `msgFrom`, `msgBody`)
         VALUES('$messageTo', '$username', '$messageBody')";

    if(mysql_query($query))
        echo "done.";
    else
        echo "Problem with Query";
}
?>
            <form method="POST">

        <div class="searchContain">
          <input name="textfield" type="text" name="messageTo" class="input search"><br />

          <textarea placeholder="Your message..." name="messageBody" class="input sendmsg" ></textarea><br />

          <button class="input" name="sendMessage">Send Message</button>
        </div>

        </form>
```

Settings.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once "../more/config/connect.php";
// Settings //


function logincheck(){
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("location: ../index.php");
}
}

logincheck();

$username=$_SESSION['username'];

$gatherInfo=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
$fetch=mysql_fetch_object($gatherInfo);

?>
```

connect.php:

```
<?php 

// Connect to the server //
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "connected") or die (mysql_error ());

mysql_select_db("ts") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

If anyone could help me fix this rather basic rookie error I'd be very grateful!

**UPDATE:**

Basically after changing the code. I've gone through the MAMP panel and changed the errors so they display. It's giving me the following error message:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

in I've never come across this error before, any ideas? It seems to fetch data from the database just fine, so I'm not sure why.

Comment: You don't check for errors. That's why you can't figure out what's wrong. Use mysql_error() after your query.

Comment: Provide the data you're trying to insert.

Comment: FYI, you *are* using depracated code and you *are not* using mysqli.

Comment: What version of PHP? mysql_* functions are deprecated in recent versions. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/12860140#12860140

Comment: add some error checking to see if your insert query is fine: `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: are you even joining the if? mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated, of course, but it returns a **string**, not a **boolean**, so you may use isset ($_POST['messageTo']) and **then escape it**... I mean.. you're already escaping them, why do you check in the if if they are escaped..? pointless, and probably wrong.

Comment: @briosheje a non-empty string will resolve to `true` in PHP.

Comment: php version is 5.4.4

I've added the form into the original post also. And for some reason mysqli doesn't work for anything i'm doing.. so I've been using mysql for the time being.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: what if messageTo is ""?

Comment: @briosheje it resolves to `false`, as expected

Comment: So what's the point of escaping it to perhaps have it false?

Comment: I have no idea, but it's the thought that counts I guess

Comment: @briosheje It has been a while, but if memory serves `mysql_real_escape_string("")` will return an empty string, which will resolve to `false`.

Comment: `$username` is undefined, therefore breaking your query. @JakeDuncan Plus, your form doesn't have a form element to support it. That and using `&& mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['messageTo'])` in your conditional statement.

Comment: Basically after changing the code... I've gone through the MAMP panel and changed the errors so they display... It's saying Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in I've never come across this error before.. any ideas? It seems to fetch data from the database just fine, so I'm not sure why.

Comment: To test, place your entire DB connection code in place where you have `include_once "settings.php";`, plus anything that's inside those included files. If it works, then it will mean that it's a path issue. It might even be a sessions issue.

Comment: Yeah it's giving me an error.. mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket...

Comment: *Hm,*... try and restart everything. *Or,* changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` - Plus, are you trying to run this entirely on your own machine or by accessing an external DB via WWW? I also suggest you Google `mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket.` - I found many possible reasons; it could be anything.

Comment: Yeah i'm currently in the process of doing so, and it's running on my Macbook pro, I'll give 127 a go! thanks for the help guys, I know how stupid I look right now :')

Comment: You're welcome and don't be so hard on yourself Jake. *Gawd,* I wish I could remember where I saw a related question a day or so ago, about someone using a MACbook with a similar problem. Include MACbook in your Google search, you may end up finding that question.

Comment: Thank's! Changing it to 127.0.0.1 didn't work, I'm going to google to try and find out what it is. It's annoying me as I could have completed so much of the project by now but it's seriously bugging me lol Thanks for the help tho!!

Answer (score 0):

try changing your query to

```
$query= "INSERT INTO `inbox` (`msgTo`, `msgFrom`, `msgBody`) 
     VALUES('$messageTo', '$username', '$messageBody')";
```

Comment: is back-ticks really necessary? none of his table name or column are reserved sql keywords.

Comment: I have had issues in some versions of PHP and back ticks solved it. Also make sure that display errors is on.

Comment: Basically after changing the code... I've gone through the MAMP panel and changed the errors so they display... It's saying Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in I've never come across this error before.. any ideas? It seems to fetch data from the database just fine, so I'm not sure why.

Comment: @JakeDuncan the comments section of a post is not the place to be asking a new question. Please [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search) for questions similar to your new one, and if you cannot find one relevant to you, [Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following

```
if (isset($_POST['sendMessage']) && isset($_POST['messageTo']) && isset$_POST['messageBody'])){

    $messageTo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['messageTo']);
    $messageBody = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['messageBody']);

    $query= "INSERT INTO inbox ('msgTo', 'msgFrom', 'msgBody') 
         VALUES('$messageTo', '$username', '$messageBody')";

    if(mysql_query($query))
        echo "done.";
    else
        echo "Problem with Query";
}
```

1. Column names should be in single inverted commas
2. You should check for the `mysql_query` to give success response.
3. do not call the same function again and again i.e `mysql_real_escape_string` was called 2 times for the same thing. Alternatively assign that to a variable, although you need not have escaped the values to check in `if` condition

Comment: those are normal commas D:

Comment: sorry, wrong name `('msgTo', 'msgFrom', 'msgBody')` those, should be ` instead of `'`

Comment: Basically after changing the code... I've gone through the MAMP panel and changed the errors so they display...

It's saying Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in

I've never come across this error before.. any ideas? It seems to fetch data from the database just fine, so I'm not sure why.